# Convert into array after Group By JPQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to convert unique values into array in GROUP BY using JPQL. Like below:

When I do a `distinct name` group by id, instead of counting i want to perform `array_agg` in `JPQL`. I know to do it in PostgreSql native query

Query:

```
SELECT age,array_agg(distinct gender) as genders FROM person GROUP BY age;
```

Result is:

```
age | genders
20  | {male}
22  | {female,male}
24  | {male}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of postge sql query that analog you want to have in jpql?

Comment: @SternK I've added